# Create Custom Class Dynamically

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project where I need to create a multitude of custom classes to interact properly with an API (While I know there might be questions on why, and such, but the short is it has to be this way).

Is there a way to create a complete custom class dynamically on the fly? So instead of

```
class person
    Private _Height
    Property Height As Integer
    Get
        Return _Height
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _Height = value
    End Set
End Property
'Continue for all properties of person
```

I would like to be able to create a new object and through other input create this dynamically.

```
dim NewClass as object
dim NewProperty as property
NewProperty.name="Height"
NewProperty.datatype=string
NewClass.AddProperty(NewProperty)
```

Is this possible? It would save me a lot of time if it is.

Comment: There are several ways to do something *like* that, but this smacks of an XY question.  `Interacting with an API` requiring dynamic classes doesnt sound right -  as an API the types and returns would have to be documented to some degree.  Getting type definitions `through other input` would give me great pause.

Comment: The API requires a class created to the specifics needed. There is a call to the API that returns the necessary parts of the class. Additionally there are many parts to this API that are in the works, or in the future, and having this setup will allow testing those pieces without updating the code.

Comment: What does `returns the necessary parts of the class` mean?  What kind of API (service or DLL)?

Comment: The API isn't the issue. I have already expressed my issues to the development team about how it's being done. The short answer is I need a custom class to handle the data, and something I can create on the fly removes a lot of steps I would have to do when things change.

Comment: How do you get/send data to the api? Does the API take a Object as the parameter of the function or a specific class? Is it JSON? ... You could add your properties/value in a dictionary instead.

Comment: The call is a JSON call yes. We are playing with dictionary's as well, but at this point I can see uses of this for other projects I have been involved in and the knowledge would help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like late binding but there are options (I like my option strict on). Like using the [DynamicObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) or the [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) class. Your question is vague so I have no idea if it can work.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim test As Object = New SampleDynamicClass()

    test.SomeProperty = "123"

    Console.WriteLine(test.SomeProperty)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Public Class SampleDynamicClass
    Inherits DynamicObject

    Private _values As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Function GetPropertyValue(ByVal propertyName As String) As String

        Return _values(propertyName)
    End Function

    Public Function SetPropertyValue(ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal value As Object) As Boolean

        If _values.ContainsKey(propertyName) Then
            _values(propertyName) = value.ToString()
        Else
            _values.Add(propertyName, value.ToString())
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function TryGetMember(ByVal binder As GetMemberBinder,
                                           ByRef result As Object) As Boolean
        result = GetPropertyValue(binder.Name)
        Return If(result Is Nothing, False, True)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function TryInvokeMember(ByVal binder As InvokeMemberBinder,
                                              ByVal args() As Object,
                                              ByRef result As Object) As Boolean
        result = GetPropertyValue(binder.Name)
        Return If(result Is Nothing, False, True)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function TrySetMember(binder As SetMemberBinder, value As Object) As Boolean
        Return SetPropertyValue(binder.Name, value)
    End Function
```

Comment: I had something like this for a class that was lengthy and fluid.  Rather than String for the value, you could create a small class to store the original type so it can be converted back (`Value.ToString()` will be problematic with some things like Point and Size - of course we dont know if that is an issue.  I dont think that would directly work for the OP, but coupled with a customer converter (assuming the call TO the API takes json) it may work. its hard to say when the OP will only tell you what they think you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim person = New With {Key .Height = 12}
Dim personTypes = New With {Key .Happy = 1, .Sad = 2}
Dim personsAndTypes = New With {Key .Person = person, .Type = personTypes}
```

The question is kind of vague, but if you have no need for other fields and methods, or reuse [Anonymous Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)

Comment: The question is vague because it's a theory question. I am trying to find out if this is possible. Your suggestion here is still hard coded, I need dynamic.

    for each entry as string in list
        dim newproperty as property
        newproperty.name = entry
        newclass.addproperty(newproperty)
    next

I need to be able to do that